# installation of Windows x64

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I have started to install windows7 x64 on my system through DVD and it is still in process after 2 days.

In past it took only only  half an hour to install. What to do still wait for complete installation. what is the problem. kindly advise

Comment: Try cleaning the DVD with soapy water or get someone else to create you a USB installation with windows 7 on it.

Comment: Create a USB install disk via the [Windows Media Creator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-10-create-installation-media), as there's clearly an issue either with the current install media, DVD drive, or other hardware.  Installation takes no more than 30 - 45min on a mechanical HDD.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said "still in process after 2 days", looks like your dvd is corrupt or the file burnt to dvd is corrupt.
Try burning a working iso file to dvd and check if dvd reader is working.
There can be no  other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say why you need to re-install Windows, so I would have to assume some
catastrophic error, but some details about what happened would be useful.

In case of catastrophic error, the most likely explanation for an old computer
is hardware, which your problem also seems to indicate.

The most likely component to have failed is the hard disk.

These are only guesses. More information is required for a better opinion.